Express the connection between roots
$\DeclareMathOperator\elim{lim}\DeclareMathOperator\Lim{Lim}\DeclareMathOperator\lmb{lmb}\DeclareMathOperator\Lmb{Lmb}\DeclareMathOperator\mts{mts}$There are two similar functions; they determine the dependence of the values ​​of similar equations
\begin{gather*}
x = L e^{s x} \iff x = \elim_s(L) \\
x = e^{L x^s} \iff x = \lmb_s(L).
\end{gather*}
For positive parameters, in the region of convergence of their power series, both have two positive roots.


Through power series we can only obtain zero roots of these functions
\begin{gather*}
\Lim_{s, 0}(L) = L + 2s\frac{L^2}{2!} + (3s)^2\frac{L^3}{3!} + (4s)^3\frac{L^4}{4!} + \dotsb \\
\Lmb_{s, 0}(L) = 1 + L + (1 + 2s)\frac{L^2}{2!} + (1 + 3s)^2\frac{L^3}{3!} + (1 + 4s)^3\frac{L^4}{4!} + \dotsb.
\end{gather*}
We need to find an analytical method, a formula for obtaining the first root of zero.
It is known that the dependence of these roots is the same for both functions:
$$
\frac{\Lim_{s, 1}(L)}{\Lim_{s, 0}(L)} = \left(\frac{\Lmb_{s, 1}(L)}{\Lmb_{s, 0}(L)}\right)^s.
$$
lim is any root. Lim is a specific root, it is indicated by the number 0 or 1 after the parameter "s"
I tried this:
let's take special cases
$s=1$, and
$L=.01$ and $L=.1$.
\begin{gather*}
a=\Lim_{1, 0}(.1) = 0.1118325591589629648 \\
b=\Lim_{1, 1}(.1) = 3.5771520639572972184 \\
b/a=31.9866780377671590 \\
A=\Lmb_{1, 0}(.01) = 0.01010152719853875327 \\
B=\Lmb_{1, 1}(.01) = 6.47277512439400469474 \\
B/A=640.7719344982143479.
\end{gather*}
It is very similar that in the formula that shows the dependence of the first root on the zero root, the natural logarithm of $1/L$ divided by $L$ is used
\begin{gather*}
10\ln10=23.02585092994 \\
100\ln100=460.5170185988091368
\end{gather*}
There are still some factors and/or terms missing.
Perhaps there is a method similar to different roots of the logarithm
$$Ln_{1}(L)=Ln_{0}(L)+2pii=ln|L|+i(arg(L)+2pi)$$

[tag:root-systems] is about something else entirely, so I have removed it.  It's not quite clear to me what you're asking, starting with the fact that you seem to be defining a function of a real variable called "$\lim$" (?), and then introduce capitalised versions of your one-subscript functions with two subscripts, and an undefined 3-subscript function "mts", so I didn't venture further tagging beyond [tag:real-analysis], but please at least add a top-level tag. \ Please use TeX, not images, for your equations. I have transcribed your images; please check if it represents what you intended.

lim is any root. Lim is a specific root, it is indicated by the number 0 or 1 after the parameter "s"

In my first edit, I incorrectly transcribed the definitions of $b$ and $A$ according to your original version; my apologies.  I notice that you fixed the subscripts, but the actual functions applied still did not match.  I edited them again to match what you had in your original version.  I hope that this was correct.

Thank you. Everything is correct now. But why doesn't anyone give advice? How can one find first root $$Lim_{s,1}(L)$$ via zero root $$Lim_{s,0}(L)$$

Re, for myself, it is because I don't know the answer, or even enough how to improve the question. However, the downvotes indicate that some users find this question "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."  While no-one is obliged to leave a comment indicating the reason for their downvote, perhaps you could see if you can show your research effort, and make your question or its motivation clearer.

You seek the two real solutions $x_0(L,s)$ and $x_1(L,s)$ of the transcendental equation
$$x=Le^{sx},\;\;x,L,s>0.$$
These can be expressed in terms of the Lambert W function,
$$x_0(L,s)=-\frac{W_0(-L s)}{s},\;\;
x_1(L,s)=-\frac{W_{-1}(-L s)}{s}.$$
The expressions cannot be simplified in terms of elementary functions.
Similarly, the two real solutions $y_0(L,s)$ and $y_1(L,s)$ of the equation $x=e^{Lx^s}$ are given by
$$y_0(L,s)=\left(-\frac{W_0(-L s)}{L s}\right)^{1/s},\;
y_1(L,s)=\left(-\frac{W_{-1}(-L s)}{L s}\right)^{1/s},$$
hence the solutions $x_n$ and $y_n$ are related by
$$y_n(L,s)=(x_n(L,s)/L)^{1/s}.$$

This is right. Thank you. But I need to know the formula to find x1 from x0. Ln has a similar formula.

the formula you are asking involves a ratio of Lambert W-functions: $$x_1=x_0 \frac{W_{-1}(-Ls)}{W_0(-Ls)}.$$ This cannot be simplified in terms of elementary functions.

So no one knows how to find $$W_{-1}$$ through $$W_{0}$$?

the two functions are related in a transcendental way, by the equation $W_0e^{W_0}=W_{-1}e^{W_{-1}}$; there is no relation in terms of elementary functions.

Thank you, Carlo Beenakker! You understood everything correctly. It's a pity that I don't know English.

So another root can only be found by iteration?
